# how to sum up total in angular?

Tags: angular

I want to sum the column of a table in angular but it does not work: for example if I want to sum the `2000` and `3000` and `4000` it gives me `200030004000`, but I want to sum it means `9000`, it is concatenation.

**client.component.ts**

```js
clients: Client[];
total: number=0;

constructor(private clientService:ClientService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.clientService.getClients().subscribe(clients => {
        this.clients=clients;
        this.total = this.getTotal();
    });
}

getTotal() {
    return this.clients.reduce((total, client) => {
        return total + client.balance;
    }, 0)
}
```

**client.component.html**

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h4 class="text-right">Total : {{ total | currency:"USD": "symbol" }}</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like it is doing string concatenation instead of adding numbers.

Comment: return total + +client.balance;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```js
...
return total + Number(client.balance);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
Because the balance you are getting is in string maybe

```
getTotal() {
    return this.clients.reduce((total, client) => {
      return total + parseInt(cliient.balance);
    }, 0)
}
```